# Big O Complexity function

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory

Why does this code have complexity O(1)?

```
function logAtMost5(n) {
  for ( let i = 1; i <= Math.min(5,n); i++ {
    console.log(i)
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This function does at most 5 iterations. Which is a constant.

A constant has O(1) complexity.

If there was `n` instead of `Math.min(5,n)`, it would have n iterations which would be linear O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Simply because the for loop will not iterate more than 5 times, it's iterations will not exceed a fixed constant.

[Graph of y = min(x,5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jawmJ.png)